# Redis session expired after 20 minutes, why?

Tags: c#, azure, redis, session-state

I use redis cache (azure servers)

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = user.Id;
```

After 20 minutes `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]` returns `null`.

I use `Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider` for my custom sesson.

What is the best way to slide the session when I call `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]`

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="SERVER" accessKey="KEY" ssl="true" throwOnError="false" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'slide the session'? Do you have a 20 minute timeout set for the session in your config?

Comment: Thanks, Vsevolod for editing :)

Comment: No, I don't have it. It is by default I suppose in redis

Comment: Have you tried to set it to some value in the provider options?

Comment: No, there is no setting for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690522.aspx

Comment: It's set on the `sessionState` element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But even if I change the value to 100 minutes, then in 100 minutes it will be expired for some reason, even if I call some variable from the session during that time range. It works properly with regular SessionState

Comment: Well, the session eventually expires, what are you expecting of it?

Comment: It should be slided.

Comment: Like with the regular session, no?

Comment: Currently trying the approach:
When I call variable, then at the same time I update the session variable, like this: var userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]; // Get value

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = userId; // Refresh it immediately to increase timeout for the next 20 minutes

Comment: I think that's the only thing to do at the moment as looks like it's not supported

Comment: yeah. Will have to do it. Thank you Vsevolod for your help.

Comment: This solution still didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

When I call variable, then at the same time I update the session variable, like this:

```
var userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]; // Get value 
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = userId; // Refresh it immediately to increase timeout
```

Comment: This still didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

you not set timeout config,the default timeout configration is 20 minutes.
try this

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore" timeout="120">
```